# Get object inside array with volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to retrieve the objects inside a json array such as `id` and `brand` within `creditcard`.

```
{
"result_count": "2",
"total_no_of_rows": "2",
"status": {
    "status_code": "-1",
    "status_text": "Success"
},
"cards": [
    {
        "creditCard": {
            "id": "CRC-9C7I2BGN8RJY",
            "brand": "AMEX",
            "first6": "376449",
            "last4": "3005",
            "store": true
        },
        "method": "CREDIT_CARD"
    },
    {
        "creditCard": {
            "id": "CRC-FXDA9E2YCWWQ",
            "brand": "ELO",
            "first6": "636297",
            "last4": "7013",
            "store": true
        },
        "method": "CREDIT_CARD"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the request below unsuccessfully because it returns card with no values.

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, response -> {
                arrayData.clear();
                try {
                    JSONArray cards = response.getJSONArray("cards");
                    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject token = cards.getJSONObject(i);
                        CardList card = new CardList(
                                token.getString("id"),
                                token.getString("brand"),
                                token.getString("first6"),
                                token.getString("last4"),
                                token.getBoolean("store"));

                        arrayData.add(card);
                    }
                    Log.v("arrayData", String.valueOf(arrayData));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("arrayDataError", String.valueOf(e));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.v("arrayDataError", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    });
```

Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: did you enqueue the volley request?

Comment: @EliasFazel please, could explain your question better?!

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#simple

Comment: Ok. hadn't done yet but I uncomment Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(req); with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follows the solution for those who need it:

```
JSONArray cards = response.getJSONArray("cards");
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject token = cards.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject creditCard = token.getJSONObject("creditCard");
                card_method = token.getString("method").equals("CREDIT_CARD") ?
                        getString(R.string.creditcard) : getString(R.string.debitcard);
                CardList card = new CardList(
                        creditCard.getString("id"),
                        creditCard.getString("brand"),
                        creditCard.getString("first6"),
                        creditCard.getString("last4"),
                        creditCard.getBoolean("store"));
                arrayData.add(card);
            }
```